# Grades for a student

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to use the valence api's to pull student grades. However I get a forbidden error when I try to do so. I am using https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com/index.php to test this. The user is assigned a role that has access to all grades.

and trying to `GET /d2l/api/le/{version}/{orgunitid}/grades/`

```
Status 
Unknown error occured (HTTP status 403)

Response
Forbidden
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What are the values for `{version}` and `{orgunitid}` you are passing in the `GET` request?

Comment: I think I was passing the wrong orgunitid.. I got the results back with the correct course offering id.. however I don't know how to get a course offering id from course offering code.

Comment: You could try getting a list of courses with this route: GET /d2l/api/lp/(version)/enrollments/myenrollments/. Append query param orgUnitTypeId=3 to filter just courses. The entries returned here will help you map course names to orgunitids.

Comment: As of Learning Suite v10.3.0 and forward, you can also look up org unit property records and filter on org unit name or code (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-orgstructure-); however, you will have to have user credentials for a user that has permission to inspect the overall org structure.

Comment: We are on Learning Environment 10.2.0 SP5. I am also using a utility account that has access to grades for all users. The previous SOAP based call had a method GetCourseOfferingByCode that returned a CourseOfferingInfo object that I am looking to retrieve.